# Not able to create a OmniStudio Developer org

Tags: developer-edition, omnistudio, developer-org, omniscript

Is it necessary to have your company as a partner company? I have tried creating Omni studio org multiple times with multiple emails but never received any org or even an auto-response email regarding it. Can anyone help?
Is anyone still able to create an org using this link:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/promo/orgs/omnistudiotrails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signup for the org using your personal email and country as US or India.
Example:
Country: United States
Postal Code: 94016

Comment: This actually worked for me. I tried with country Australia almost 10 times but I wasn't able to create. Thanks!